# Complete reference of Android XML styles

Tags: android

Google's Android documentation is relatively complete when it comes to classes, interfaces, and such. But I have not been able to find a complete reference of all the style-related XML -- not just backgrounds and padding and whatnot but also action bar options, etc. Does such a thing exist or is it really just scattered amongst the other docs?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really show all of the options contained in each style in the docs, but just has a reference to the tag.

[I find that using GitHub is the best bet](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) :-\

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to hwrdprkns answer, I would suggest the Android Resource Navigator for Chrome. It's an extension that allows you to type "arn" in the URL bar / omnibox and then begin searching whatever resources (XML styles) you want. When you click on any of the results it will ink you to the GitHub when you select one.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-resource-navigato/agoomkionjjbejegcejiefodgbckeebo